# Get values from map

Tags: ruby, hash

I have this hash:

```
PAYMENT_TYPE_TO_CURRENCY_AND_COUNTRY_MAPPING = {
  zimpler: {'EUR' => ['FI'], 'SEK' => ['SE']},
  qiwi: {'EUR' => ['RU', 'KZ'], 'RUB' => ['RU'], 'KZT' => ['KZ'], 'USD' => ['UA']},
  payu: {'CZK' => ['CZ'], 'PLN' => ['PL']},
  entercash: {'EUR' => ['AT', 'DE', 'FI'], 'SEK' => ['SE']},
  davivienda: {'USD' => ['CO']},
  banco_de_chile: {'USD' => ['CL']}
}
```

I want random currency and country from the structure using `sample`. I did:

```
currency = PAYMENT_TYPE_TO_CURRENCY_TO_COUNTRY_BY_PAYMENT_TYPE_MAPPING[payment_type].keys.sample
country = PAYMENT_TYPE_TO_CURRENCY_TO_COUNTRY_BY_PAYMENT_TYPE_MAPPING[payment_type][currency].sample
```

I get:

```
undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass (RuntimeError)
```

How I can implement this?

Comment: Please post the complete error message.

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: I doubt I understand why would not you at least try my answer since it works perfectly and does exactly what you need (you might use `payment_type` where I used `:qiwi` because you did not provide the way `payment_type` is defined.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a variable that doesn't exist? Your structure is called `PAYMENT_TYPE_TO_CURRENCY_AND_COUNTRY_MAPPING` but you're sampling on `PAYMENT_TYPE_TO_CURRENCY_TO_COUNTRY_BY_PAYMENT_TYPE_MAPPING`.

I tried your same code but used the same variable containing your structure and it works for me:

```
PAYMENT_TYPE_TO_CURRENCY_AND_COUNTRY_MAPPING = {
  zimpler: {'EUR' => ['FI'], 'SEK' => ['SE']},
  qiwi: {'EUR' => ['RU', 'KZ'], 'RUB' => ['RU'], 'KZT' => ['KZ'], 'USD' => ['UA']},
  payu: {'CZK' => ['CZ'], 'PLN' => ['PL']},
  entercash: {'EUR' => ['AT', 'DE', 'FI'], 'SEK' => ['SE']},
  davivienda: {'USD' => ['CO']},
  banco_de_chile: {'USD' => ['CL']}
}

payment_type = :qiwi

currency = PAYMENT_TYPE_TO_CURRENCY_AND_COUNTRY_MAPPING[payment_type].keys.sample
country = PAYMENT_TYPE_TO_CURRENCY_AND_COUNTRY_MAPPING[payment_type][currency].sample
```